# Why can expressions be carried across multiple lines in function calls but not assignments?

Tags: python, parameter-passing, expression, variable-assignment, indentation

I just realized that it's possible to stretch a statement across multiple lines when it's passed as a parameter to a function:

```
print(1 == 
  1)
```

However, doing the same thing during a variable assignment raises a `SyntaxError`:

```
x = 1 ==
  1
```

Why does the first example work but the second one yields a `SyntaxError`?

Comment: [What is the rationale for closing "why" questions on language design?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170394/what-is-the-rationale-for-closing-why-questions-on-a-language-design) -- if you know what the syntax *is*, and you know how to write correct code in light of that syntax, you don't have "an actual problem that you face" in the sense referred to in https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python recognizes open brackets, braces, and parentheses as indicating that the statement is not finished.  Thus, the function call "naturally" is allowed to span lines.

This parser convention doesn't apply to expressions in which there is *not* a required balanced enclosing punctuation.

Note that strings also cannot cross line boundaries.

Comment: Demonstrating `x = (1 ==` ...newline... `1)` as working syntax might make this even more clear.

Answer (score 0):

One other way to do this is with the continuation character (\) as in...

```
x = 1 == \
  1
```